# New relic python agent exception handling

Tags: python, newrelic

I have been looking if we need to try/except the new relic python agent API calls. I want to know if for some reason newrelic servers are not reachable, will the agent call raise an exception.

I am using `agent.record_exception()` api [api](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/python-agent-api/recordexception-python-agent-api)

I am looking around the docs but unable to get any hint.

Comment: Are you integrating this in a script/flask app/django?

Comment: the application framework is pyramid